# starting wsgi as a service fails on startup

Tags: services, systemd-unit

I am trying to deploy a flask application inside my WSGI container. I have tried to deploy it by symply executing the same commands within [Service] tags in the unit declaration; this means that I have independently executed the following commands:

```
   cd /home/sat/myproject_webapp
   FLASK_ENV=docker
   sudo /home/sat/myproject_webapp/venv/bin/python wsgi.py --port 80
```

After executing these, everything works fine and the server is successfully deployed. But when starting the service that contains exactly the same orders, it fails. The declaration of the service is as follows:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target webapp-services.service
Requires=webapp-services.service

[Service]
User=root
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/home/sat/myproject_webapp
Environment=FLASK_ENV=docker
ExecStart=/home/sat/myproject_webapp/venv/bin/python wsgi.py --port 80

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I suspect that there is an error in the Environment field's declaration related to the usage of "" or '', but nothing worked.

Comment: You first have `cd /home/sat/myproject_webapp`, but then `WorkingDirectory=/myproject_webapp`. These directories are different.

Comment: yeah sorry, I have modified those for the post, but they are actually the same.

Comment: Try "systemctl status <name of service>" and  look at "journalctl -xe".

Comment: Solved! It was an error on the flask_env configuration, I was indicating the wrong instance.